# WebSocket on node js server (ReferenceError)

Tags: node.js, npm, websocket

According to the npm docs :

> ws is a simple to use, blazing fast, and thoroughly tested WebSocket client and server implementation.

So I have installed it

```
npm install ws
```

and tried a little test on Node js file :

```
const Websocket = require('ws');

const ws = new WebSocket('ws://www.host.com/path');
```

but I receive an error :

> ReferenceError : WebSocket is not defined

What am i doing wrong please ?

**EDIT :**

It was just a typing error.

I used

```
const Websocket = require('ws');

const ws = new WebSocket('ws://www.host.com/path');
```

But I have to use :

```
const WebSocket = require('ws');  // WebSocket with camelCase...

const ws = new WebSocket('ws://www.host.com/path');
```

Comment: I had the same trouble and was stumped until I came across your answer! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your using the client logic on the server, try

```
const WebSocket = require('ws').Server;

const ws = new WebSocket({ port: 8080 });
```

Comment: Thanks I'm new user of Node.js I tested it but it's the same error

Comment: This answer is correct.  https://www.npmjs.com/package/ws#server-example clearly shows that this code is correct.  Are you sure the `ws` library was installed correctly and in the correct directory?

Comment: @OlivierJ. well there is indeed another issue with _your_ example in that your casing isn't consistent i.e. your declaring as `Websocket` but calling as `WebSocket` - that's probably where your issue is. If you used the example code in my answer it should work just fine.

Comment: This was just because you used `post` and not `port` my apologies but I don't think I was explained well my problem. I tried to use WebSocket connexion inside Node.Js server so how can I define the `WebSocket` uri ? Sorry I'm begining from 0...

Comment: @James : this is completely true, this was my error, I will edit my post. Thank you again

Comment: @OlivierJ. in terms of setting up your server, have a look at the [express example](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ws#expressjs-example). In the meantime, to get you up & running quickly (i.e. client side) you can use the  test [echo server](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ws#echowebsocketorg-demo).